# Mayavi - Change the size of an object?

Tags: python, mayavi

I am using Mayavi in a python script.  All works fine except that I am unable to change the size and position of my colorbar.

I generated the colorbar like this:

```
    colorbar = mlab.colorbar(title='Frequency', orientation='vertical', label_fmt = '%.1f')
```

What do I do to change its size and move it to a different position in the scene?  I have been at this for days and have been unable to get anything to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the position like this :

```
colorbar.scalar_bar_representation.position = [0.1, 0.9]
colorbar.scalar_bar_representation.position2 = [0.8, 0.05]
```

Cheers,

R.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the cleanest solution, but try

```
colorbar.scalar_bar_representation.proportional_resize=True
```

After doing that I was able to drag a bar around the screen and resize it.  If you want to do some more polished things, look at some of the attributes in scalar_bar_representation (reading the source here would probably be very helpful).

Comment: great tip, I used this to determine the `position` and `position2` attributes needed to execute the other answer